# I want to get the exact message out of this error

Tags: php, mysql, exception

I understand I have to include mysql_errno y mysql_error here somewhere instead of 'Query Failed' and I tried with $results as an argument but i have not found out how.

If someone can help me out, thanks:

```
static function execSQl2($query)
{
/*
        Execute a SQL query on the database
        passing the tablename and the sql query.
        Returns the LAST_INSERT_ID
*/

    $db = null;
    $lastid = null;
    //echo "query is $query";

    try
    {
        $db = Model::getConnection();
        $results = $db->query($query);
        if(!$results) {
            throw new Exception('Query failed', EX_QUERY_FAILED);
        }
        $lastid = $db->insert_id;
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        /*  errors are handled higher in the
                object hierarchy
        */

        throw $e;
    }

    Model::closeConnection($db);
    return $lastid;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're using some sort of framework.  You should look at it's documentation for how the database class being used reports errors.

Answer (score 4):

```
 throw new Exception(mysql_error(), EX_QUERY_FAILED);
```